# How to transform hexadecimal to float in binary representation with IEEE standards

Tags: floating-point, binary

Example: with hexadecimal number 45100000H, what's the representation of its float number with IEEE standards.

My computing process is:

45100000H = 0100 0101 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000

We got a positive number because of the first 0

The exponent is the following 8 numbers 1000 1010.

Since it is offset binary, we got the Inverse code 0000 1010 if we inverse the first number.

The value of exponent is 2^1 + 2^3 = 10

So my conclusion is 45100000H = +1.125*2^10

But the answer is +1.125*2^11. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> The exponent is the following 8 numbers 1000 1010.

Not quite. The **code** for the exponent is the eight bits 1000 1010. This is not the exponent; it is a number that tells us what the exponent is.

To decode those bits, first we interpret them in binary, then we subtract the bias, 127. In binary, they would be 128 + 8 + 2 = 138. Subtracting 127 gives 11. So the exponent is 11.

> Since it is offset binary, we got the Inverse code 0000 1010 if we inverse the first number.

No, that is not how the exponent code is decoded.

Completing the decoding of the whole number, the primary significand bits are 001 0000 0000 0000 0000. When the exponent code is not all zero bits or all one bits, we decode the significand by putting “1.” in front of the primary significand bits and interpreting them as binary. So we form “1. 001 0000 0000 0000 0000” and interpreting them as binary (ignoring the spaces), which gives 1⅛.

So the bits 0100 0101 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 represent + 2<sup>11</sup> • 1⅛ = 2304.

Answer (score 0):

Eric already explained the details, but here it is in tabular form which you might find helpful:

```
  DECODED = 2304.0 :: Float
                  3  2          1         0
                  1 09876543 21098765432109876543210
                  S ---E8--- ----------S23----------
   Binary layout: 0 10001010 00100000000000000000000
      Hex layout: 4510 0000
       Precision: Single
            Sign: Positive
        Exponent: 11 (Stored: 138, Bias: 127)
  Classification: FP_NORMAL
          Binary: 0b1.001p+11
           Octal: 0o4.4p+9
         Decimal: 2304.0
             Hex: 0x9p+8
```